# before fill out the text field, jump to next text field in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to put username and password to appropriate text field in a web page. first I find the element by id for email and put the email for it and then find the element by id for password and put the password for it, but before fill out the email field in text box it jump to the password field and complete the task, I needed to wait for fill the email and after that jump to the password field.

I tried implicit and explicit wait, but both are not working please help me
I am using firefox with selenium 2.44

```
    // Enter Email
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");

    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Email")));
    //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Enter pwd     
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Click the sign in button
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Edited: here is my complete code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("gmail");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rso\"]/div[2]/li[1]/div/h3/a[1]")).click();

        // Click the sign in button
        driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Enter Email
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");


        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Email")));

        //Enter pwd     
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("@@@@xxx");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Click the sign in button
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        }

}
```

Comment: You said, **it completes the task**, without entering in **email field**. From the code, it seems like a **Sign in Page**. So, does it throw some error related to **"Please fill the Email field"** or **"Email field cannot be blank"** or something ?

Comment: set   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @Subh it fill some characters in email. think my email is example@gmail.com, then it fill "exam" and other parts are go to the password field, it is not wait for completely fill the email field,

Comment: @Lakna: If this is a public site you are trying to automate, can you share the link please ?

Comment: I am trying to automate to login my gmail account. I can send my complete code if you need

Comment: I just executed the login in gmail using **Java+Selenium+Firefox**. The code works fine and the **email is filled completely**. So, please attach your complete code. There must be something missing I guess.. Thanks.

Comment: I have attached the complete code that I have written

Comment: Your code seems to work fine at my end, though I would suggest you to **refrain from using Implicit waits** so many times in the code, **because once assigned at first, its scope applies to the whole class**, meaning each time selenium tries to find an element, it will implicitly wait for that amount of time. On the other hand, which version of FF and Selenium are you using ?  I am using **Selenium 2.44.0** and **Firefox 31.2.0 ESR**

Comment: I am using selemium 2.44 and firefox 33.1, is it enough to use one statement of implicit wait ?

Comment: Yes.. You can check this link, where it is clearly mentioned: [http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits). Let, me add my code in the answer below. Please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing , first enter the email field and then do a get text on email field it will give you what you have entered, if it is true go on to Password text box.

Comment: it is not completely enter the email, before complete the email it goes to the password field. so when I get text on email field, it always false

Comment: as you saying email id is typed into pwd text box that means , pwd text box element id is same as email id text box, or  it might be changing at run time , sometimes it happen element id changes dymamically, while your exection is happening check the elements id's on the webdriver window and verify if they are correct

Answer (score 0):

**Although your code works fine when I tried it at my end,** still I've modified the existing code. Please see if that works for you:

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("gmail");

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Gmail - Google']")).click(); //Modified with a relative xpath

        /*This part of clicking on Sign In Button wasn't coming up for me, 
          So, I've commented it. Please Uncomment, if this page is coming up for you*/
        // Click the sign in button
       // driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Enter Email
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("testing@gmail.com");

        //Enter pwd     
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("tesing&*78");

        // Click the sign in button
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar situation. My application had a postback script that was causing the text box to jump to another location. My work around was to .click() the webelement first to get back into  it and then do a .sendkey(). Hope this is helpful for you as well.